# Elasticsearch has been created an index when stop Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

While running bin/logstash -f logstash.conf --debug , it does not create an index in Elasticsearch. Until I stoped logstash, and then it created an index in ES.

The issue will happen if I add function " codec => multiline " but it needs to use codec => multiline.

Could someone please help me how to fix on Logstash.conf ?

```
input { 
    file {
        type => "json-log"
        path => "/logfile/*.json"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        ignore_older => 0
        codec => multiline { 
                    pattern => "^\[" 
                    negate => "true"
                    what => "previous"

            } 
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
    match => ["message", "%{GREEDYDATA:msg}"]
    overwrite => [ "message" ]
  }
    json {
            source => "msg"
    }  

}

output {
      elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["xxxxx.com:9206"]
    index => "fpngilog-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
    #document_type => "hola"
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: I think it means that the multiline codec is matching all the lines it's receiving and collapsing them in a single event. Since all the lines are matched, they "stay" in the multiline codec and are only flushed when you stop logstash. As a solution, you could add the [auto-flush](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html#plugins-codecs-multiline-auto_flush_interval) option, or change your codec configuration so that not all the lines match.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Auto-Flush is working fine now. ^_^